# How do I set the comments column width when editing phpmyadmin table structure

Tags: phpmyadmin

The input width is too short when editing table structure in phpmyadmin.

How to set the input width of column "comments" show in the picture red mark?
[image]

I saved

```
$cfg['MinSizeForInputField'] = 600;
$cfg['MaxSizeForInputField'] = 600;
$cfg['LimitChars'] = 600;
```

into phpMyadmin\config.inc.php and then restart Apache but all of the input width still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this css style in

phpMyAdmin\themes\pmahomme\css\common.css.php

```
#table_columns tbody input[name^="field_comments"] {
  width: 25em;
}
```

and press ctrl+f5 to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cfg['CharTextareaCols'] 600
```

> Number of columns and rows for the textareas.
>       This value will be emphasized (*2) for SQL query textareas and (*1.25) for SQL textareas inside the query window.
>       The Char* values are used for CHAR and VARCHAR editing (if configured via $cfg['CharEditing']). 
>    [Source](http://www.moduldesign.ro/eng/pma/Documentation.html)

Comment: I appended $cfg['CharTextareaCols']=600; still the same.

Comment: `$cfg['LongtextDoubleTextarea'] TRUE`
    Defines whether textarea for LONGTEXT columns should have double size.`

Comment: I viewed Features#tab_Text_fields. http://localhost/phpmyadmin/prefs_forms.php?form=Features#tab_Text_fields

I think my phpmyadmin already set $cfg['LongtextDoubleTextarea'] true by default.